# High latency in urlfetch with google app engine

Tags: java, latency, google-app-engine

We have a Java application that make use of urlfetch calling an external api. We are having issues with the request time. When we do a request in a local environment we have a mean time of 300ms, however in production we have times of 1s or 1.4s.

This is the code we are using:

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();

try {

      URLFetchService fetcher = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();

      URL url = new URL( String.format( API_URL, productsIds ) );
      Future<HTTPResponse> future = fetcher.fetchAsync(url);


      HTTPResponse responseHttp = future.get();
      byte[] content = responseHttp.getContent();

      response = new String(content);

      System.out.println("request time :" + (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - start.getTimeInMillis() ) );


} catch ( Exception e ) {
    LOGGER.log( Level.SEVERE, "Error calling api : " + e.getMessage() );
}
```

Is Google doing any kind of validation that produces this time increase?

Is there a way to reduce the request time?

Comment: What URL are you hitting?

Comment: It is probably not a java problem, but some sort of network timeout. If you could emulate the same request with some other technology (curl, or browser) it could help a lot.

Comment: [This same issue is being discussed in the App Engine Google Groups forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/ryYsvyEily4/COLb4zOwosYJ), and some excellent profiling / network-testing suggestions have already been posted (if I do say so myself)

Comment: @jirungaray, it is a company API url, I think I can not post it in a public forum.

Comment: @peterh that is exactly what we did. We used curl and saw that the response time is a lot smaller than if we use gae

Comment: @Nick thank you we will try what you said to see if we find a solution

Comment: well it does make a lot of sense that hitting a locally routed URL from a local environment is much faster than the time it takes Google to contact your servers and back.